# Simple objects in Quasi-coherent sheaves are isomorphic to structure sheaves of a closed point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quasicoherent-sheaves

Need to prove that simple objects in Quasi-coherent sheaves are isomorphic to structure sheaves of a closed point.

"Simple object" means that there is no non-trivial subobject.

I encountered this problem in Vakil's FOAG(April 1, 2023), 6.5.L. I have proved that if the simple sheaf is a simple module on every affine open set, we have the result. The approach is to notice that, under this assumption, the simple qcoh sheaf is supported at a closed point of the scheme X on every affine open set, then we can construct a skyscraper subsheaf.

But I don't know how to continue.

My attempt to prove the "fact" (*the simple qcoh sheaf is a simple module on every affine open set*) is as the following.

Suppose we have **M** on **Spec A**, **M** is an **A**-module, and since **M** is not simple, we have a submodule of **M** isomorphic to **A/p**, where **p** is a maximal ideal of **A**, but not necessarily a closed point.

I'm thinking of constructing a skyscraper at **p** with **A/p**. But since the closure of **p** is not necessarily inside **Spec A**, I can't do the zero extension and get an injection from the skyscraper into the quasi-coherent sheaf.

PS: the scheme **X** may not have any closed point. I think maybe there is a more subtle way of proving using the sheaf morphisms which I have not learned systematically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No idea why this question is closed. This question is fine for a starter user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observe, it suffice to classify simple objects in $\mathrm{QCoh}(\mathrm{Spec} \ A)\simeq A-\mathrm{mod}$. Let $M\ne0$ be a simple $A$-module. Then for any $x\ne0\in M$, there is a sub-module $0\ne Ax\subset M$, so by simplicity, $M=Ax\simeq A/I$, where $I=\ker(x)=\{a\in A:ax=0\}$.

Now, $I$ must be maximal, since otherwise there is an ideal $A\supsetneq J\supsetneq I$, and $J/I\subsetneq A/I$ is a non-trivial sub-module. But $A/I$ with $I$ maximal is exactly the structure sheaf of the closed point $I\in \mathrm{Spec} \ A$.

---

For an arbitrary scheme $X$, let $\mathcal F\ne0\in\mathrm{QCoh}(X)$ be a simple object, so for some $x\in X$, $\mathcal F|_{\{x\}}\ne0$. Then for any closed sub-scheme $i_x\colon \{x\}\hookrightarrow X$, there is a surjection $\mathcal F\to i_{x*}\mathcal F|_{\{x\}}$, which must be an isomorphism. Then the same argument as in the affine case applies.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't know how to apply it to general Qcoh(X), and that's the place I got stuck in. Could you please interpret it with more detail?

Comment: So this is the more advanced restriction map in the latter part of the book. I see, thank you so much!

Comment: Hello Kenta, for the single point {x}, how do you give it a scheme structure? Note that in the definition of a skyscraper sheaf, one can only give the one-point space a ringed topological space structure (x,O_{X,x}), but this is not a scheme.

Comment: I'm giving {x} the structure of the spectrum of k(x), the residue field.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right! But I still have several concerns. F|x is an O_{X,x}-module, not necessarily a k(x)-module; next, for x\to X to be a closed subscheme, x must be a closed point. But there are schemes without any closed point (in fact this phenomenon was my primary concern).